# What is Bonjour Linux IPTables Firewall Ports?

Tags: iptables, firewall, bonjour

I'm trying to configure my `iptables` in order to allow `Pidgin` to use `Bonjour` protocol, now according to: [Bonjour for Windows doesn't work due to firewall settings](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts2235), I have to allow `Multicast DNS / (5353/udp)`.

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ uname -a
Linux wcmisdlin02.uftmasterad.org 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 16 11:21:38 CDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo iptables -L | grep mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:mdns 
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ grep '5353/udp' /etc/services 
mdns            5353/udp                # Multicast DNS
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

I'm still unable to communiate w/ others through `Bonjour` even though `iptables` is configured. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried fluxing iptables rules to see if it works better?

Comment: `Bonjour` service works fine w/out `iptables`, but the idea to get it to work w/ `iptables`